# How/Can I use Nvidia GPU in Handbrake?

Tags: nvidia, gpu, video-editor, video-conversion, handbrake

**system configuration**

```
intel i5 9300H
nvidia 1650(m)
ubuntu 20.04
gnome 3.3
nvidia driver 450
```

Recently I tried to crop and re-encode a video to x265 using Handbrake .

I switched to Nvidia on demand in prime profile
and right clicked on Handbrake icon and selected launch using dedicated graphic card

Yet when I see handbrake is not using Nvidia Graphic card
and in preferences of Handbrake I have no option to enable or to choose Nvidia Graphic Card

My question is

1. Does Handbrake supports GPU encoding ?
2. If yes then how to use / enable it in Handbrake ?
3. If no then what are the better(simpler) alternative of Handbrake that support cropping and converting to H265 using nvidia graphic card

Comment: I'm not very good with the CLI version, but if you use the `HandBrakeCLI` you can use `--encopts="gpu=0"` etc. switch with it that should use the GPU instead.  See https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/technical/video-nvenc.html